# How can I get screenshot in specific tag and screenshot including scroll with Chromedriver

Tags: python

I'm trying to get screenshot with webdriver.Chrome. In specific, I have to get  tag screenshot.  tag's width is fixed in 800px, and height has dynamic length. But the screenshot image is cropped in another position that I cannot expected. When you see code below, 'p_width_height' tag is left border tag in total_image. I can't get left border screenshot image. Also, how can I get image if left border div tag is long including scroll.

[total_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erQif.png)

[specific_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HQkP.png)

```
cur_path = os.getcwd()
new_path = os.path.join(cur_path, 'screenshot')
if os.path.isdir(new_path):
    pass
else:
    os.mkdir('screenshot')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.path.join(cur_path, 'chromedriver'))

driver.get("localhost:8000" + request.get_full_path())
print("driver.get_window_size: ", driver.get_window_size())
print("driver.get_window_size: ", driver.get_window_size())
element = driver.find_element_by_id('p_width_height')
if element:
    location = element.location
    size = element.size
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file(os.path.join(new_path, cur_problem_id + "_total" + ".png"))
    png = driver.get_screenshot_as_png() # saves screenshot of entire page
    driver.quit()
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(png))
    left = location['x']
    top = location['y']
    right = location['x'] + size['width']
    bottom = location['y'] + size['height']
    im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom))  # defines crop points
    print(left, top, right, bottom)
    im.save(os.path.join(new_path, cur_problem_id + ".png"))  # saves new cropped image
```